# Center view during simple scale animation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to do a scale in/out animation for activity/framgent transition

here are the two animations :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="80%"
        android:fromYScale="80%"
        android:toXScale="80%"
        android:toYScale="80%" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />

</set>
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >

        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%"
            android:fromYDelta="0"
            android:toXDelta="0"
            android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

Use it like that :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_to_behind);
```

The problem is that the activity doesn't scale down in the center of the screen, it stick to the top/left of the screen

Any idea what wm i missing ? Or doing wrong ?

Comment: set a pivot for that. center it at 50%

Comment: what do you mean by pivot ? rotate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a pivot to your scale animation. Add this on your xml:

```
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
```

Your scale should look like:

```
  <scale
    android:fromXScale="100%"
    android:fromYScale="100%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="80%"
    android:toYScale="80%" />
```

Comment: that does the trick, but how come the scale animation is immediat ? even thought i put a duration

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but bear in mind that `overridePendingTransition` is for activities. If you want to animate a fragment transaction use `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` instead.

Comment: Yes you are right. What i mean is that the duration of the animation is normally 500ms but the scale is immediat, am i missing an attribut or miss-using one ?

Comment: And you're talking about animating an activity transition? Also, is the content of `slide_in_right.xml` the first piece of code you have?

Comment: i'm talking about animating activity yes, just after StartActivity(...). all the animation code is here. I use nothing else

Comment: When are you calling overridePendingTransition? Have you tried increment `android:duration="500"`?

Comment: i'm calling it the line after StartActivity(...); and yes i tried 1000ms too. Still the same

Comment: You should call that on the 2nd activity that you're transitioning to. On `onCreate` and before `setContentView`

Comment: Also you're trying to scale from 80% to 80%... That's the same scale factor. So you won't see any scale. What are you trying to do? Scale down to 80% or scale from 80% to 100%?

Comment: Again you are right thanks, i think friday i was kinda tired, how could i not see that Oo (could you edit your answer please ?) scale 100% to 80%